# how to delete 2 equals Attachments of one record

Tags: apex

It happens that sometimes I have 2 or more equals Attachment for one record(i.e. one Case with 2 equals Attachment a). Now I'm trying to write a trigger to delete the copies of one attachment and leave only one of them.
Now I'm able to build a Map with the record's Id and a list of Attachment, but I need a tips now on how Can I compare and delete one attachment in a list.

Now I write this:

```
trigger SetField on Case (after insert) {
List<Case> c=[select Id,Origin,Working_Status__c,Environment_Type__c,
              Contract_Number__c,AccountId,SuppliedEmail
              from case where id in: Trigger.new];
List<Attachment> allegati= [select Id,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId In:c];
Map<Id,List<Attachment>> allegatipercaso=new Map<Id,List<Attachment>>();
    for(Attachment a:allegati){
        if(!allegatipercaso.containsKey(a.ParentId)){
            allegatipercaso.put(a.ParentId, new List<Attachment>{a});
        }else{allegatipercaso.get(a.ParentId).add(a);}
    }
```

Any tips would be really appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 attachments you could simply run a check in a loop and compare their bodies, but I'm pretty sure that will slow down everything, especially when working with multiple (and) large attachments.

So I'd probably do the following:

- First compare their `ContentType`s and sort the attachments based on it(so all *pdf*s are with other *pdf*s and not with *jpeg*s or anything else)
- Then, within each group, I'd find groups that have the same `BodyLength`
- And then I would run a check on `Body` on the attachments with the same `ContentType` **AND** `BodyLength`

The first 2 checks are actually quite simple, so they won't consume much resources. The last one, however, can be quite consuming if you don't filter out the attachments that are certainly not duplicates, especially if you update/insert in bulk and/or have really big attachments

---

These are just my thoughts, I did not implement anything like this (yet), but if I would this would be my first attempt

Comment: Thank you I just tried somenthing like that but I have the error " Exceed CPU limit", maybe it's somenthing I could do with batchable apex